# How do I bind JavaScript call to GetQuerySuggestion to SearchBoxEx control

Tags: development, search, ajax, soap, search-box

**Resolved below**

Well the title says most of it but here is the background:

On the search results page, when you type in the search box it does some soap calls in JavaScript too **"GetQuerySuggestion"**.

On site pages you add a **SearchBoxEx** web part/control template and it doesn't have this same JavaScript feature.

The question is how do I get the same functionality on the **SearchBoxEx** Web part?

update

```
<SPSWC:SearchBoxEx id="SearchBox" runat="server" 
GoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/Intranet/meta_search_go.png" 
GoImageActiveUrl="/_layouts/images/Intranet/meta_search_go.png" 
DropDownMode="HideScopeDD"
AppQueryTerms="scope:&quot;/&quot;"
ShowAdvancedSearch ="true"
UseSiteDefaults="true" 
QueryPromptString="Search"
SearchBoxTableClass="searchbox"
TextBoxWidth="210"
FrameType="None"
PreQuerySuggestions="true" />
```

From suggestions so far I have tried PreQuerySuggestions and QuerySuggestions, the value here is true|false according to msdn.... But no joy.

(Should of been more clear it was as a control template) oops! (Btw the AppQueryTerms is so I can modify the scope dynamically with javascript)

Any ideas?

AND FIXED

```
<SPSWC:SearchBoxEx id="SearchBox" runat="server" 
GoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/Intranet/meta_search_go.png" 
GoImageActiveUrl="/_layouts/images/Intranet/meta_search_go.png" 
DropDownMode="HideScopeDD"
AppQueryTerms="scope:&quot;/&quot;"
ShowAdvancedSearch ="true"
UseSiteDefaults="true" 
QueryPromptString="Search"
SearchBoxTableClass="searchbox"
TextBoxWidth="210"
FrameType="None"
ShowQuerySuggestions="true" />
```

Comment: I would like to do this cleanly if possible, I can't find the event hook in FireBug to replicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.searchboxex_properties.aspx

This is what I have been hunting for all day, many links and suggestions but thanks goes to almostSharepointMaster because I found the PreQuerySuggestions on one of the links you provided, which led me to find ShowQuerySuggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you have looked at this yet?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.query.getquerysuggestions.aspx

and

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/fbdf2210-d7a7-4e0a-bf02-378e5da3d8da/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, yes I have unfortunately it isn't binding the required function, in JavaScript. Basically this code already exists, BUT and it is a BIG BUT I have no idea what function is called, how it is bound to the search box and what is run between the input and the soap call.

Comment: Ok so let me get this straight you want to add a suggest as you type feature in a searchboxex webpart? if so than this should hopefully solve the problem: you need to got to "Search Box Web Part settings" or Ctrl+4 and search for suggestion and it should popup ;) there is a list with how to configue the webpart to add it in: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg576963.aspx , This might help too: http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/sharepoint-blog/working-with-sharepoint-search-part-1-14359  I hope these are what your looking for :)

Comment: I couldnt find any for 07 but here is the link anyways http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee329476(v=office.12)